# Carrierwave with MiniMagick is adding black background color to transparent .png when using remote_url with resize_to_[fit/fill/ect]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave

Expect the following Uploader, when I upload .png with no background via remote_XXX_url the :thumb version using a resize_to_fit is converted with a black background.

The original file uploaded is as the same as the original with the transparent background.

If I upload the image via a file_input the issue is not occurring.

Therefore I deduce that the issue is only occurring when doing a resize_to_XX transformation on remote_XXX_url file. Do you know what is happening ?

carrierwave (2.2.2) -- mini_magick (4.11.0) - The original image has a transparent background.

Image used : https://whirlpool-cdn.thron.com/delivery/public/thumbnail/whirlpool/pi-81b54ac7-7614-4a32-bdd1-a3f79db530d5/sckne7/std/320x320/859791401010.jpg?fill=zoom&fillcolor=rgba:255,255,255&scalemode=product

[image]
Thumb Image resized_to_fit

[image]
Image without resizing

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  def store_dir
    "#{ENV['AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME']}/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_allowlist
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png svg webp)
  end

  version :thumb do
    process resize_to_fit: [150, 150]
  end

  def filename
    @name ||= "#{mounted_as}_#{timestamp}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  def timestamp
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_timestamp"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, Time.now.to_i)
  end
end
```

Comment: What version of Imagemagick? What version of libpng delegate?  Are they both current? Your original image is in color?  Why is your image without resizing black and white?  Does it fail if you use Imagemagick in command line mode outside your Carrierwave?

Comment: @fmw42 carrierwave (2.2.2) -- mini_magick (4.11.0) (I made a mistake I was using MiniMagick) - The original image has a transparent background. I've changed the images in the question so that it is more understandable

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know Carrierwave.  If you just use -resize in the command line for Imagemagick, does it make the background black?  Are you saving the result to PNG or JPG. JPG does not support transparency and will remove it and make the background black.

Comment: Using ```convert original.png -resize 100x100 new.png``` is working correctly. Results is .png - That is why I think the issue is due to the remote_url as the resizing if working correctly if the file is uploaded via an input form

Comment: Imagemagick can access the file via HTTP or HTTPS. But you may need to modify your policy.xml file to give permission to use HTTPS. Can you use the URL for the input in the command line and see what happens? If that fails, then check your policy.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Your original file appears to have the extension `.jpg` but actually contains a PNG image.

**ImageMagick** itself is smart enough to spot that and it won't cause you any trouble. I don't know or use `carrierwave` but it appears to be carrying forward the original `.jpg` extension and forcing **ImageMagick** to write a JPEG which will make transparent regions black. I think it's this line:

```
@name ||= "#{mounted_as}_#{timestamp}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
```